# Hadronic decay experimental result

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, large-hadron-collider

I am looking for experimental results of hadronic decays cross section of the two following decays: $\Delta^{+} \rightarrow p +\pi^0 $ and $\Sigma^{*0}\rightarrow p + K^{-}$

I have already computed the theoretical result:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{P(\Delta^{+} \rightarrow p +\pi^0)}{P(\Sigma^{*0}\rightarrow p + K^{-})}= 4
\end{equation}
using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. Now I want to compare it to the experimental result.

Anyone knows where I can find it?

Comment: Case is significant in particle symbols. Protons are symbolized with a lower case letter $p$.

Comment: Have you tried the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/contents_tables_baryons.html), the source of all wisdom for the [Δ](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf)  and the   [Σ](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-tab-baryons-Sigma.pdf)? Choose the 1385 in the latter case, for the decuplet member.

Comment: And of course the listings, http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/rpp2019-list-Delta-1232.pdf and http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/rpp2019-list-sigma-1385.pdf . You were not taught how to use them in class?

Comment: Nope, I didn't even know they exist. Thanks, I'll try to figure out how they work.